# White Space issue under header photo and first section

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding (so go easy on me) doing this project for fun and I'm pretty close to being complete but I can't seem to get rid of this 2-5 px white space dividing my header from the first section. See the screenshot below:
[image]

I set all element margins to 0 such as

```
* { 
margin: 0 
}
```

but this didn't help.

the following code uses tables with inline CSS. Can somebody help me!

```css
table.t00 { 
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0;
}

table.t00 th { 
  max-width: 630px;
  max-height: 474px;
}

table.t01 { 
  height: 162px;
  width: 640px;
  background-color: #1ab3ba;  
}

table.t01 tbody { 
  text-align: center;
  color:  #f1f1f1
}

table.t01 th { 
  width: 636px;
}

table.t02 { 
  width: 640px;
  background-color: white
}

table.t02 tbody { 
  text-align: center;
  width: 634px;
  height: 291px;
}

table.t02 th { 
  width: 634px;
}

table.t03 { 
  width: 634px;
  height: 320px;
}

table.t03 tbody { 
  text-align: center;
  width: 634px;
  height: 320px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

table.t03 th { 
  width: 634px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

table.t04 { 
  width: 640px;
  height: 84px;
  background-color: #052f66;
}

table.t04 tbody { 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
      <body>
          <table class="t00">
            <tbody>
                <th style="margin: 0;">
                    <img
                      class="header-image"
                      src="victory-club header.jpg"
                      alt="header for victory clubs membership"
                       />
                </th>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table class="t01">
            <tbody>
              <th>
                <p style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;  font-size: 28px; margin: 10px 0;">Your Member ID is:
                  <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 36px; margin: 0;">FL-9999999</h2>
                  <p style=" font-size: 14px;
                  font-style: italic; margin: 5px 0;">Please keep this for your records</h4>
                  </th>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table class="t02">
            <tbody>
              <th>
                <p style="padding-top: 3%;
                color: #052f66;
                font-size: 28px;
                font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
                text-align: center; width: 634px; margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px">
                  Member Benefits
                </p>
                <br>
                <p style=" color: #898989;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;">These are just some of the amazing benefits that come with your <br> Victory Clubs membership!</p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p style="background-color: #eeeeee;
                height: 44px;
                padding-top: 26px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 12px;
                color: #378bac;">Exclusive events and parties at local venues for Victory Clubs members only.</p>
              <div style="background-color: white;
              width: 634px;
              height: 7px;"></div>
                <p style="background-color: #eeeeee;
                height: 44px;
                padding-top: 26px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 12px;
                color: #378bac;">Deals and Savings at hundreds of retail and restaurant locations. 
              <div style="background-color: white;
              width: 634px;
              height: 7px;"
              ></div>
                <p style="background-color: #eeeeee;
                height: 44px;
                padding-top: 26px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 12px;
                color: #378bac;">Exclusive Perks through your School.</p>
              </div>
              </th>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table class="t03">
            <tbody class="schedule">
              <th>
              <p style=" padding-top: 3%;
              color: #052f66;
              font-size: 28px;
              font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
              text-align: center;">
                Schedule Now!
              </p>
              <br>
              <p style=" color: #898989;
              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
              font-size: 14px; margin: 0 59px;">Schedule and pass your initial drug test now so you can start enjoying all the perks and benefits your Victory Clubs membership has to offer.
              </p>
                <br>
                <br>
                  <button  style="display: inline-block;
                  padding: 10px 30px;
                  font-weight: 300;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  border-radius: 100px;
                  border: 1px solid;
                  color: white;
                  border-color: #dc1d40;
                  background-color: #dc1d40;">SHEDULE MY DRUG TEST</button>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

                <p style="color: #898989;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px; margin: 0 59px;">
                  You’ll receive an email letting you know your free 90-day subscription has been activated once you pass your drug test.
                </p>
                <p style="color: #052f66;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 16px; margin: 0 59px;">
                  <b> Keep up the great work!</b>
                </p>
                <br>
              </th>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table class="t04">
            <tbody>
                <th>
                    <ul style="padding: 20px;">
                        <li style=" list-style-type: none;
                        display: inline-flex;"><a style="color: white;" href="" target="_blank">FB</a></li>
                        <li style=" list-style-type: none;
                        display: inline-flex;"><a style="color: white;"href="" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li style=" list-style-type: none;
                        display: inline-flex;"><a style="color: white;" href="" target="_blank">Insta</a></li>
                        <li style=" list-style-type: none;
                        display: inline-flex;"><a style="color: white;" href="" target="_blank">Youtube</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p style="  color: #898989;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 10px;
                    height: 32px;">© All Rights Reserved. Privacy Policy | Accessibility Policy | Terms & Conditions</p> 
                </th> 
          </tbody>
        <table>
    </body>
```

Comment: can you install the code snippet as it works

Comment: Your code doesn't match your image

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code:

```
table.t00 th img {
    display: block;
}
```

One thing about images is that they have a default `display: inline-block` which makes them leave margins around other elements ... putting block display eliminates this effect

---

Also try adding

```
table.t00 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

instead of having `separate` which is the default behaviour

Comment: that helped but now it's like one px. I added all the code so you can load it and test it out!

Answer (score 0):

`<table>` have border-spacing and by default it's value is `2px`..so change it to `0` ....

```
border-spacing: 0px;
```

for both of your tables...t00 and t01

```
table.t00 { 
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.t01 { 
  height: 162px;
  width: 640px;
  background-color: #1ab3ba;  
  border-spacing: 0px;    
}
```